# CK2 Hospital questions

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My demesne has several hospitals (about 6).  My primary county hospital is maxed out, but I want to move my capital to Constantinople (more central location in my empire). So 2 questions: Do hospitals stack benefits? And, do I always get the benefit of my "best" hospital, or only my capital's hospital?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following only apply to the province the hospital is located in:

- Hospital level
- Disease resistance
- Tech spread bonus

The following stack from all hospitals in your realm (including vassal hospitals):

- Prestige
- Piety
- Tech Points

The following stack only from hospitals you directly own:

- Temple Vassal Opinion

---

Note: tested on Patch 2.8.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The hospital's benefits are localized to the county, so the only ones that really stack are the upgrades that give you piety and prestige.